# How can I make the if function in python try the values from the range for "a" and return the correct answer

Tags: python, if-statement

```py
a = list(range(0,10))

if a + 6 == 10:
    print(a)
```

I am trying to make the numbers between 0 and 10 be individually substituted into `a` and when it finds the right answer then it will stop and return the value of `a`. So, in this case, just to return `4`.

I keep getting this error

> ```
> can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
> ```

Comment: did you check `for in` or any other iteration techniques?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
def func():
    for a in range(10):
        if a + 6 == 10:
            return a
```

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate over the `list` `a` and then check your condition for each element of `a`

```
a = list(range(0,10))

for i in a:
    if i + 6 == 10:
        print(i)
```